# LIS3DH temperature acquisition

Tags: temperature, particle.io, particle-electron

I'm trying to get temperature from LIS3DH sensor (accelerometer with integrated temperature sensor)

I'm using Particle electron board that contain that sensor.

The datasheet provide too few information

set TEMP_EN and ADC_EN from TEMP_CFG_REG register.

I read value that fluctuate continuously and does not correspond, to temperature.

Do you know which register I have to consider to get it works ?

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet states that to connect ADC3 to the temperature sensor, set both TEMP_EN and ADC_EN of the TEMP_CFG_REG register to 1.

Then read OUT_ADC3_L to get the raw value and use the Temperature sensor characteristics table for conversion.

Hope this helps.